# Nuget Package recovery

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I try to open a customer project, but i get the error:

Error at Recovery of Nuget Packages. Couldn't find the Version "xxx" of the package "xxx".

I get this for 12 Nuget package.

Also the automatic recovery don`t load the missing files.

Using the Visual Studio 2015.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109666/restoring-all-nuget-packages-in-a-visual-studio-2015-solution

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure whether those 12 NuGet packages are custom package.
 If yes, you could not recovery those packages from the NuGet.org directly, you should get them from your customer.

If not, please check your package sources: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json is enable. 
For the temporary workaround, you can download those packages from [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/), then set those packages into your local packages folder(Default path is under the solution's folder).